# Что делать, если вопрос, не являющийся точной копией, закрыт как копия?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, дубликаты, переоткрытие-вопросов

Имеется такой вопрос: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/) Oн закрыт как копия такого вопроса: [Проверка на отсутствие циклических ссылок при сборке из нескольких проектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/51432/)

На первый взгляд, всё логично. Однако я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Для решения задачи сформулированной в первом вопросе, закрытом как копия, я на регулярной основе пользуюсь https://github.com/Fody/Costura Я хотел написать свой ответ, что бы поделиться этим решением с другими посетителями сайта. Однако, на закрытый вопрос ответить нельзя. С другой стороны, мой ответ не является ответом на второй вопрос, потому что там фокус был на решении проблемы циклических ссылок, и предложенный вариант с ILMerge, работает, однако внедрение зависимостей как ресурса в данном случае не сработает, потому что циклические ссылки так и останутся, и, соответственно, мой ответ для этого вопроса будет неверен.

Таким образом я не могу написать этот ответ в первый вопрос потому что он правильный, но вопрос закрыт, и я не могу написать этот ответ во второй вопрос, потому что хотя вопрос открыт, но для него этот ответ неверен.

Очевидно, я могу просто пройти мимо, но мне хотелось бы узнать, есть ли у меня рабочие альтернативы. В частности, я подумал, что можно было бы отредактировать закрытый вопрос и попробовать его открыть. Однако мне не приходит в голову, как его красиво и лаконично отредактировать.

Кто нибудь может предложить решение?

Answer (score 7):

Если вопрос **закрыт неправильно**, то есть несколько путей:

1. добавить комментарий, что вопрос закрыт неправильно;
2. исправить вопрос, чтобы довести его до более товарного вида;
3. добавить голос за переоткрытие;
4. призвать открывашек из <s>чата открывашек</s> общего чата;
5. создать обсуждение на Мете;
6. призвать модератора тревогой.

Все пункты опциональны.

Должен отметить, что призывать модератора имеет мало смысла, потому что модератор может предпочесть — и, скорее всего, предпочтёт — ориентироваться на уже высказанное мнение сообщества, а не высказывать своё профессиональное мнение, даже если оно есть.

Голые голоса за переоткрытие без комментариев и правок также с большой вероятностью будут проигнорированы. Лучше всего сочетать.

Самый надёжный вариант — создать обсуждение на Мете, потому что тогда будет полноценное обсуждение, но прибегать к этому методу следует, только если не помогло всё остальное, то есть когда стандартных инструментов оказалось недостаточно.

Comment: "до проделывания остальных", "всё остальное не помогло" - что-то тут лишнее

Comment: @vp_arth Исправил.

Comment: _It is alive O:

Comment: @Suvitruf Последний раз я здесь был недавно, постил комментарии в теме про эвфемизмы. Просто комментарии быстро перестали быть.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю, есть ли установленная процедура, но мне кажется наиболее логичным следующий подход:

1. Если вопрос *X*, который был закрыт как дубликат вопроса *Y*, *более общий*, чем *Y*, и у вас есть к нему также более общий ответ, то имеет смысл объявить *X* основным, а *Y* — его дубликатом. Возможно, для этого понадобится перенести (или скопировать) ответы из *X* в *Y*. Скорее всего, такую хирургию может сделать только модератор; кроме того, ответы на *Y*, возможно, придётся подредактировать, чтобы они соответствовали новым условиям вопроса.
2. Если как вопрос *X*, так и *Y* освещают лишь часть общей проблемы, то имеет смысл создать «канонический вопросоответ»: сформулировать самому вопрос *Z*, дать на него наиболее общий ответ, и закрыть *X* и *Y* как дубликаты *Z*.

Answer (score 3):

Два решения

- Ответьте на вопрос, для которого ваше решение будет верным - на него есть ссылка в комментариях - [Статическое внедрение dll в сборку (C#)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457513/)
- Задайте новый вопрос, для которого ваше решение будет актуальным, добавьте в него в нем ссылки на все 3 существующие вопросы и решения, укажите особенности. И сами же дайте на него ответ.