# Модераторы не читают вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Я [задал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826584/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F/826595?noredirect=1#comment1318453_826595) с целью узнать что делают скобки в модуле (именно скобки, не сам модуль), однако мой вопрос был отмечен модератором как дубликат, и даны ссылки на вопрос "Зачем библиотеки обертывают в (function() {…})()?" и "Самовызывающиеся функции JavaScript" в которых не содержится ответа на мой вопрос.

При этом догадываясь что такое может произойти, я написал в вопросе что понимаю зачем это (инкапсуляция) делается и что вопрос совершенно не об этом.

Из чего я могу сделать вывод что модераторы или не читают текст вопросов, или я слишком плохо объясняю.

Что делать в случаях когда модератор закрывает твой вопрос потому что неправильно понял его?

---

Сегодня утром я обнаружил что [один из моих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820780/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-%D0%B2-js) был отмечен дубликатом, тем же пользователем, что отметил [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826584/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F/826595?noredirect=1#comment1318453_826595). В этот раз ситуация еще абсурднее, если в предыдущем случае произошедшее можно было скинуть на относительную схожесть тем и довольно запутанную формулировку вопроса, то этот отмеченный вопрос не имеет ни единого сходства с [вопросом предложенным на замену](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591547/javascritpt-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Comment: Зачем удалять вопрос?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1879/10105

Comment: Извините, но напомнило вот это. https://bash.im/quote/450283

Comment: И ещё свежий пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835470

Answer (score 8):

Вас закрыл не модер, а обычный юзер с дубльмолотом (способностью единолично закрывать некоторые вопросы).

---

Решение: предложить переоткрытие вопроса.
Если найдётся достаточное количество считающих что закрывающий ошибся, вопрос откроется.
Если таких желающих не будет - возможно это Вы не понимаете что закрывающий прав.
Тогда попробуйте в комментариях/чате выяснить это, не стоит на мету это выносить.

Comment: На мету это может и стоит выносить в случае непонимания в комментариях, а так всё всё верно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov можно вынести, если провалилась открывашка. В данном случае автор не дождался пока голосование по открытию пройдёт.